# Assist in getting data from cache

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This screen is somewhat working. On the first time you open the screen, only the splash screen shows up. Go back then open the screen again then the data shows up. **I need help in getting the data from cache and show it the first time the screen opens.**

I need the screen to show splash screen while doing the saving and retrieving data from cache then show the actual data after that on the first time you open the screen.

```
    const [dataList1, setDataList1] = useState([]);
    const [cacheData, setCacheData] = useState(null);

    // Function to get data from cache
    const getDataFromCache = async () => {
        const data = await cache.get(cacheKeys.BENEFITS_CACHE_KEY);

        setCacheData(data);
    }

    // Get data from cache
    useEffect(() => {
        getDataFromCache();
    }, [])

    // Store data to cache
    useEffect(() => {
        if (dataList1.length > 1) cache.store(cacheKeys.BENEFITS_CACHE_KEY, dataList1);
    }, [dataList1]);


    useEffect(() => {
        
        var benefitsArr = [];
        var benefitsDetailsArr = [];

        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {

            if (authUser) {

                db
                .collection('members')
                .doc(authUser.uid)
                .get()
                .then(user => {

                    benefitsArr.push(...user.data().benefits);

                    db
                    .collection('benefits')
                    .get()
                    .then(snapshots => {
                        snapshots.forEach(doc => {
                            if (benefitsArr.includes(doc.id))
                            {
                                benefitsDetailsArr.push(doc.data());
                            }
                            
                        })

                        // Save results to a useState constant
                        setDataList1(dataList1 => ([...dataList1, ...benefitsDetailsArr]));
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))

                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))

            }
        })

        return unsubscribe;

    }, []);

    if (!cacheData) return <SplashScreen />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of this line

```
if (!cacheData) return <SplashScreen />
```

You should create a show/hide state  then do

```
if (show) return <SplashScreen />
```

Then in your function

```
const getDataFromCache = async () => {
    const data = await cache.get(cacheKeys.BENEFITS_CACHE_KEY);

    setCacheData(data);
    setShow(false) // <-- hide the splash
}
```

Comment: This worked. Don't see the splash screen anymore though. Might need to reduce network speed to see the slow network behavior. Thanks alot!

Comment: I'm not sure what splash screen u use but you should check out packages like react-native-splash-screen